# Whether to use 'OR' or 'AND'

Tags: terminology

My doubt is: while solving equations or inequalities consisting of absolute values when should we use the conjunction 'OR' and when to use 'AND'? whats the difference between them ?

Comment: The question is a bit too generic. Could you gives us some equations/inequalities you have encountered? We could then help you understand accordingly.

Comment: @Marvis-example:|x-4|=1 ,  |x-4|is less than or equal to 2

Answer (score 2):

OR means one (or more) of the choices must be true; AND means they must all be true.  In each case you need to think which you need.  For your examples, $|x-4|=1$ is true whenever $x-4$ is 1 OR -1.  $|x-4|\le 2$ is only true when $-2 \le x-4 \le 2$, so you must have $-2 \le x-4$ AND $x-4 \le 2$

Comment: ok... thanks i got it

Comment: does |x-4|=o means that x is such a point which is zero distance away from 4?

Comment: @meg_1997:  Yes.  When an absolute value is zero, you can just remove the absolute value signs.  $|y|=0$ is the same as $y=0$ because there is only one number with absolute value $0$.

Comment: please will you tell whether to use the conjunction 'OR'or 'AND'? in example: |p| is greater than or equal to4

Comment: @meg_1997:  what values of $p$ make $|p| \ge 4$?

Comment: -5,-4,....  and 4,5....

Comment: @meg_1997:So you have two classes of solution.  Look back at the original definition and see if you can figure it out.

Comment: should i use 'OR'?

Comment: @meg_1997:  yes, you have $p \le -4$ OR $p \ge 4$

Comment: @ Ross Miilikan : ok, hey will u please see my question here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/153681/absolute-value-on-a-number-line#comment354240_153681